# C# regex match until next first group

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to parse a error message from one of our suppliers.

It looks some thing like this

```
LabelOne: Value 1 LabelTwo: Value 2 : LabelThree: Value 3
```

Result should be

```
[{"LabelOne", "Value 1"}, {"LabelTwo", "Value 2"}, {}, { "LabelThree", "Value 3"} ]
```

Note empty match because of empty gibberish : after Label2, this is fine.

This regex kind of works

```
(\w+):\s+([^:]+ )
```

But it skips the 3 on last value (Value instead of Value 3)

But it breaks if the value contains for example a timestamp 22:00:36 I want it to match until next Label. Any ideas?

Comment: Like this? `(\w+):\s+(.*?)(?=\s*\w+:|$)` https://regex101.com/r/7DJ3uj/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird - It doesn't match on the time requirement.

Comment: @Enigmativity Maybe I missed that one, can you give an example? I thought like this would match https://regex101.com/r/8GqfmY/1 I think the OP means that it breaks a timestamp due to the colon in `22:00:36`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern you are using a negated character class `[^:]+` which can not cross matching a colon like in `22:00:36`

You might use an assertion to the next whitespace char followed by 1 or more word chars and a colon:

```
(\w+):\s+(.*?)(?=\s+\w+:|$)
```

- `(\w+)` Capture 1+ word chars in **group 1**
- `:` Match literally
- `\s+` match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(.*?)` Capture as least as possible chars in **group 2** (non greedy)
- `(?=\s+\w+:|$)` Positive lookahead, assert either 1+ whitespace chars followed by 1+ word chars and a colon to the right, or assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/irb4zY/1)

If you want to match at least a word char in group 2, you can use `(\w.*?)` instead of just `.*?`

Another option could be for example matching a non whitespace char other than a colon with `([^\s:].*?)`

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. It almost works. My example wasnt close enough to the real deal, the value can have several whitespace and then your regex breaks, https://regex101.com/r/FWWOn0/1

Comment: @Anders There can be multiple ways around this, for example assert not a digit directly after the colon:

`(\w+):\s+(.*?)(?=\s+\w+:(?!\d)|$)` https://regex101.com/r/BVVjR9/1 Or a assert a word char without a digit `(\w+):\s+(.*?)(?=\s+\w+:\s*[^\W\d]|$)` https://regex101.com/r/5Jwd1J/1 If there is always a space after the colon, then `(\w+):\s+(.*?)(?=\s+\w+:\s|$)` https://regex101.com/r/OQ92A7/1

Comment: I altered your to remove that stand alone colon. (\w+):\s+(.*?)(?=\s+\w*:(?!\w)|$) It seems to work.  You think its solid?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/11nbsv/1

Comment: @Anders You could do it like that, but for the examples `(?!\w)` is always true as there is a space after the colon. In that case you could also write `(\w+):\s+(.*?)(?=\s+\w+:\s|$)`